# Why does one Route fail and the other work?

Tags: laravel, api

I am using Laravel to serve both my website and a stateless API.  I use `Passport` with a token set in the cookie to Authenticate the API, this is handled by `Passport`.

I make calls to the API using `axios` within `vue.js`

I was getting an issue with an API call that was returning `Unauthorized`, all other requests were fine, by playing around I have arrived at the finding that

```js
    this.$axios.get('session/'+this.session+'/posts')
            .then(response => { console.log(response.data); });
```

```php
    Route::get('/session/{code}/posts'      , 'PostController@posts');
```

works; whereas

```js
    this.$axios.get('session/posts')
            .then(response => { console.log(response.data); });
```

```php
    Route::get('/session/posts'     , 'PostController@posts');
```

does not (returns 401 Unauthorized).

In the first example the `$code` value is simply an obfuscated ID and is not related to authentication, it is a string of characters.  Also, `session` refers to an internal Application object and is not related to the php session at all.

This is in my Routes service provider:

```php
        Route::prefix('api')
            ->middleware('auth:api')
            ->namespace($this->namespace.'\API')
            ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));
```

This sets a token in a cookie (`laravel_token` by default), and uses that to authenticate.

Other routes are successfully authenticating through this, when I add the variable to the route, it works!

Can anyone explain to me why the second version gives an Unauthorized response?

It appears to be the `auth:api` guard that makes this distinction, but I don't know where in the Laravel framework the actual `check()` code is.

Comment: Could you post the laravel.log?

Comment: Check so you don't have middleware present.

Comment: Sorry for delay, didn't get notified of comments on this.  @AlessandroD'Orazio there is nothing in the log, no error, just a valid 401 response

Comment: @Anuga the only middleware used is the auth:api and my own to check licencing, it passes the licencing middleware successfully, it is the auth:api (supplied by Passport I think) that is failing and therefore returning 401

Comment: If you're using the api middleware, should the route be`/api/session/posts`? Since the prefix api is defined in the route service provider.

Comment: @swonder Yes, this is set globally in the `axios` instance, so the actual call has `api/` added to the front

Comment: Cool, is there a `__construct()` in the PostController?

Comment: @swonder yes, it just has `$this->middleware('licence');` in it.  This is my own Middleware component, I've been able to add debugging to it, so it does get called and passes successfully

Comment: Are you absolutely sure in your request you're sending the API token required to validate the request?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194933/discussion-between-antg-and-swonder).

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check if your routes where a part of a prefix that has the auth:guard api activated. whereas you need to send api generated token to gain authorization.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean by this, but I have added detail to the question

Comment: what data are you passing on this.session?

Comment: I've edited the question to clarify this, $code is just an obfuscated ID, and the session object is an Application object it is not referring to a browser session